# Convert Map to JSON with property names in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to convert a Map to JSON string with property names in Typescript

Sample Input

```
Map<string,string[]> myMap; 

let value1:string[] = ["0","1"];
let value2:string[] = ["2","3"];

myMap.set("key1",value1);
myMap.set("key2",value2);
```

Desired Output

```
[  
   {  
      "KeyPropertyName":"key1",
      "ValuePropertyName":[  
         "0",
         "1"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "KeyPropertyName":"key2",
      "ValuePropertyName":[  
         "2",
         "3"
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid `--downlevelIteration` compiler option, use `Array.from()` instead of spread operator.

I have edited User863's code:

```js
let myMap = new Map()
let value1 = ["0","1"];
let value2 = ["2","3"];

myMap.set("key1",value1);
myMap.set("key2",value2);

let result = Array.from(myMap).map(([KeyPropertyName, ValuePropertyName]) => ({KeyPropertyName, ValuePropertyName}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let myMap = new Map()
let value1 = ["0","1"];
let value2 = ["2","3"];

myMap.set("key1",value1);
myMap.set("key2",value2);

let result = [...myMap].map(([KeyPropertyName, ValuePropertyName]) => ({KeyPropertyName, ValuePropertyName}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Just spreading the Map also returns the entries `[...myMap]` or `Array.from(myMap)`

Comment: It is saying Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.ts(2569)

Comment: @User863 I tried that, can we do without using --downlevelIteration. I'm not sure about how --downlevelIteration affects in other places.

Comment: @Rams TBH I'm not aware much about that